# Observable.Interval wait until action is done

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, intervals, observable

Observable.Interval produces value every period of time. How to make it wait until action ends before the next iteration?

Example:

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(async t => 
{
    //Here could be some long running action with different duration each iteration
    Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
    await Task.Delay(3000);
});
```

It will start action every second. How to make it wait until action is completed?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is the default behaviour - unless you introduce `async`/`await` - so remove the `async` and use `Task.Delay(3000).Wait()` instead.

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(t => 
{
    //Here could be some long running action with different duration each iteration
    Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
    Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
});
```

The contract for observables will only produce a new value once the observers are done - unless you introduce `async`.

`Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))` doesn't produce a value every second - it produces an **interval** of one second **between** the observer(s) finishing and the next one starting.

So, if you have a long running observer you'll still have a full second between one finishing and next starting.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work as expected
`code`
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(t =>
            {
                //Here could be some long running action with different duration each iteration
                Console.WriteLine("Before " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString());
                Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("After " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString());
            });
`code`
Last "After" with next "Before" won`t have 1 seconds interval.

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work as expected code 
`Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Subscribe(t => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Before " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString());
    Task.Delay(3000).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("After " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString().ToString());
 });`

Last "After" with next "Before" won`t have 1 seconds interval.

Answer (score -1):

Why not implement it yourself? 
Use [TaskFactory.StartNew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx) in a while loop or recursive method. 
Then simulate work by using [Task.Delay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Actually I want to avoid using while loop or recursive methods.

Comment: You can do something similar you know. But without passing the timespan, you can implement something that ask for action, and what you do is get that action, make it a task, and when that task completes call the action again. 
Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695499/proper-way-to-implement-a-never-ending-task-timers-vs-task